# Download documents from SharePoint using office 365 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a office 365 SharePoint site as https://myCorporateSharePoint.sharepoint.com/sites/MyApplication

I need to download some documents uploaded in this location with my application > I have already done the application configuration in the Azure AD and got the client ID and the key . Now I have to download the file from the sharepoint location . Any code snippets on this on how this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the App only context using a SharePoint helper class. To Get the App only context refer [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2016/03/07/using-add-in-only-app-only-permissions-with-search-queries-in-sharepoint-online/). Also refer the [AddIn Authorization Policies](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/add-in-authorization-policy-types-in-sharepoint).

To download a document from SharePoint, refer [here](http://www.sharepointed.com/2016/08/31/download-all-files-from-a-document-library-using-client-object-model/)